# jQuery html(htmlString) does not render properly

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is a jQuery function

```
(function($){
    $.errMsg = function(obj, str){
        if(typeof obj !== 'object'){
            return;
        }
        //
        if(typeof str === 'string'){
            obj.html(str);
        }else{
            obj.html('');
        }
    };
})(jQuery);
```

It allows me to display an error message such as:

```
$(err).errMsg('<b>Error</b>. Invalid file(s) format or size greater than 2 Mb, please retry with different documents.');
```

But no matter how I do, it renders the `<b>` tag as plain text.

I googled the issue without success, I tried `$.parseHTML, decodeURI` without success.

Can someone lend some help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You define `$.errMsg` taking two parameters, but you call it with only one argument? Am I missing something?

Comment: I am confused. But does the function — not — need an `obj` first. And then the string?

Comment: $("#foo").errMsg("bar"): `VM1202:1 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).errMsg is not a function`. It works properly with `$.errMsg($("#foo"), "<div>bar</div>"))`

Comment: You are right `Niek` and `Axnyff`. This is more a jQuery utility than a plugin. It works fine now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this if you want to write jquery plugin for showing your error messages :

```
(function($){
        $.fn.errMsg = function(str){

            return this.each(function () {
                var $dom=$(this);

                if(typeof str === 'string'){
                    $dom.html(str);
                    console.log("here");
                }else{
                    $dom.html('');
                }
            });
        };
    })(jQuery);

    $('.my-errors').errMsg('<b>Error</b>. Invalid file(s) format or size greater than 2 Mb, please retry with different documents.');
```

Comment: My bet, I just realized I was using a jQuery utility function instead of a jQuery Plugin. The actual plugin is build into `$.fn.extend` and works perfectly. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Convert the obj to a valid jQuery object

```
$( obj ).html( str )

// Or even
$( obj ).clone().html( str );

// test error message
$(err).errMsg( 'p',  '<b>Error</b>. Invalid file(s) format or size greater than 2 Mb, please retry with different documents.');
```

B